# How to change footer of UITableViewSection in a STATIC UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

You know how in the Settings app in iOS, you can select an setting from a `UITableView` of settings, and the footer of the `UITableViewSection` in which the setting cells are in will change. Like when you access your app's "Allow Location Access" settings, when you switch between "Never", "While Using App", or "Always", the text below the settings changes. In my app, I would like to achieve a similar function. I have tried reloadSection:, and I have implemented `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`, but when I call `reloadSection:` it hides my `UITableViewSection` completely. So how do you access the footer of a `UITableViewSection` of a `static` `UITableView` and change it without hiding the whole thing? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the exact code, because I don't often use Swift and I don't often work with a `UITableView`, but I would add some sort of event method that fires `On Touch Down`, then add an `if` statement that checks **the value of the selected text in the `UITableView` in question**, then have the code in your `if` statement change the text of the `UITableViewSection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the table controller's `tableView(titleForFooterInSection:)` and add there the logic to choose a string according to the state of the data. When the user taps a cell that should change the footer, call `UITableView.reloadSections(withRowAnimation:)` to smoothly change the footer.

Comment: I have tried this, but it hid the UITableViewSection completely :)

Comment: I have implemented this in my own app and works. Make sure not to implement `viewForFooterInSection:`.

Comment: I used tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .Automatic), and I have not implemented any UITableViewDataSource methods except for the titleForFooterInSection method. But the section keeps hiding!